# Filtering items with underscore using findWhere?

Tags: underscore.js

I have the following underscore code which pulls out data from an external `JSON` and displays it in a list.

```
<script type="text/template" >
    var ids = [4021401143741,4021402266418];
</script>
     <script type="text/template" class="template">
        <ul>
                <% _.each( rc , function(productTile) {
                      if(_.findWhere(ids,productTile.id){
 %>
                <li class="productTile" data-id="<%= productTile.id %>">
                <img src="<%= productTile.images[0] %>" alt=""/>
            <h3>Demo<%= productTile["name"] %></h3>
            <p><%= productTile.price.formatted %></p>

                </li>           
                <% }  }); %>
      </script>
    var listingTemplate = _.template(
               $( "script.template" ).html()
           );
```

In the external `JSON` file there are around 30 products, but I would like to only show information for 6 specific products, which I declare in this internal `JSON`:

I'm using `if(_.findWhere(ids,productTile.id){` but it's not working, is there something wrong with the way that is written?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use `findWhere`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to **findWhere** should be an object not a primitive type. As you have an array of numbers you need to use the **contains** function instead:

```
var ids = [4021401143741,4021402266418];
var id = 4021401143741; 

if (_.contains(ids, id)){
    alert('yes')
}
else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Comment: I don't think `_.findWhere` accepts an interator function.  It expects an object with named properties.

Comment: Right you are - got my finds and my findWheres mixed up!